# Jenkins Not finding the Manually installed jars to repository

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to setup a jenkin to build the maven android project on ubantu machine

```
Android SDK : android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
OS : ubantu
Maven home: /usr/share/maven3
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

Installed the android dependency using the android SDK deployer

If i run the "mvn clean install" on command line project build successfully, but if i tried with a jenkin job it's failing because it's not able to find the manually installed jars.

jenkin user anonymous

**Tried the following still facing the same issue:**

I ran into a problem, 
I added a new user by following this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-centos-6

**Steps to add a new user as root:**

```
sudo adduser jenkinadmin 
sudo /usr/sbin/visudo
```

Edit the file as below
Adding the user’s name and the same permissions as root under the the user privilege specification will grant them the sudo privileges.

--#User privilege specification

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 
jenkinadmin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Press ‘cntrl x’ to exit the file and then ‘Y’ to save it

and update the /etc/default/jenkins file JENKINS_USER to new user created above. then issue the

```
chown -R jenkinadmin /var/log/jenkins
chown -R jenkinadmin /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R jenkinadmin /var/run/jenkins
chown -R jenkinadmin /var/cache/jenkins
```

Then restarted the Jenkins jenkins and check the user has changed using a ps command 
/etc/init.d/jenkins restart
ps -ef | grep jenkins

I can see the jenkin is staring with the same new user, but still im getting the same mave repo error.

also after editing the sudouser with the below command 
sudo /usr/sbin/visudo
now I'm alsways prompt with this error

"jenkinadmin is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported"

Also I've installed the maven using the sudo apt-get install maven and this install the maven on

```
root@myBox:/etc# mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven3
Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: What changes have you made by running the command `sudo /usr/sbin/visudo`? Please paste the changes.

Comment: updated the question with the step followed to add a new user

Comment: Instead of `jenkinadmin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, try `jenkinadmin ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: what should be the group name?When adding the "jenkinadmin" user i did not create a group/add to specific group # user and group to be invoked as (default to jenkins)
JENKINS_USER=jenkinadmin
JENKINS_GROUP=jenkins

Comment: Well, i think i overlooked one of your command `sudo adduser jenkinadmin`. You are creating a new user named _jenkinadmin_. _This is not what i meant_. You already mentioned that the command works fine from command line. So you just have to run Jenkins with the same user with which you're running the command on command line.

Comment: I've logged in as root and ran the "mvn clean install" in command line there are no other users created.

Comment: Check the last few lines that i've updated in my answer. Find the user and make changes at each place i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: Yep, It's show the running user as ROOT

Comment: Ok, so make the changes at all the places specified in my answer. Once done, do a `ps -ef | grep -i jenkins` and confirm that the user has changed to `root`. Also don't forget to check the Jenkins log to see if there are any errors. You can also try opening the page in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since maven is running fine on the command line but has issues when running through Jenkins, it most probably means that it's a PATH issue. Just run Jenkins with the same user with which you're running mvn on command line.

To find out the user with which Jenkins is running, you can run this command:

```
[tom@jenkins_master ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i jenkins
ec2-user 20040     1  0 Sep15 ?        00:07:59 /etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=8009 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
tom   23248 23222  0 22:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i jenkins
[tom@jenkins_master ~]$
```

As you can see from the above output, Jenkins is running as user `ec2-user`. If you've installed Jenkins without doing any customization, then the startup script will most probably be `/etc/init.d/jenkins`. If you will open this file, it should have the following entry:

```
JENKINS_CONFIG=/etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

The above file (*/etc/sysconfig/jenkins*) contains the user name entry with which Jenkins will be running. *You should change that but you will also have to make sure that you change the ownership of other files and directories that Jenkins uses*. These can be seen from the output i pasted above:

/var/lib/jenkins/
/usr/lib/jenkins/
/var/log/jenkins/
/var/cache/jenkins/

These should do. After you make changes to the ownership and restart Jenkins, make sure to check the logs to ensure there are no permission issues. That's it.

To find the user with which you're running command on the command line, just type the following command:

```
[tom@jenkins ~]$ id
uid=514(tom) gid=515(tom) groups=515(tom)
```

`uid=514(tom)` portion of the above output confirms that you are currently logged in as user 'tom'.

Comment: I've logged in as root and running the "mvn clean install" and jenkin job is running as "anonymous" user,how do i set the path for this user ?

Comment: Job can be run as any user. It only means who triggered the build. That doesn't matter. What matters is when the job runs, with which user id is it running.

Comment: @Sam: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: Hi tried what you suggested, i've updated the question with the steps i followed, still no luck